# Filter by list length

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Given the following code, I wish to get rows with *license_no* with a list of two items. How should I phrase the filter statement?

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['1','2'],'license_no':[['John','John'],['Mary','Mary','Mary']]})
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use an apply function to get the length of the list for each row and then use the result to filter your dataframe.

```
df[df["license_no"].apply(len) == 2]
```